# Why do I get Syntax error when trying to use .kv file, even though I have kivy installed?

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.9

So I am following this Kivy course:  [Kivy Course - Create Python Games and Mobile Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8Imtec4ReQ)

And the peculiar thing is that I don't experience this issue when I am creating .kv files on my windows PC. But I am on my Mac and this error occurs whenever I try to run my .kv file in my terminal:

```
#Code for reference
#This is the .kv file

MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
```

```
#This is the main.py file

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


class ThelabApp(App):
    pass

ThelabApp().run()
```

```
#This is the error message when I try to run my .kv file:#
File "/Users/marcus/Desktop/kivy-thelab/TheLab.kv", line 3
    <MainWidget>:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There is also some other error message that pops up in Visual Studio code when I hover over the `MainWidget`code:
`Kivy files require #:kivy !ex`

It's really weird because the main.py code works fine, I am able to use Kivy in the python file with no problems, I can display buttons, labels without any error messages. But .kv files doesn't seem to work and only gives me syntax errors.
And yes, before people start asking: All of my files are in the same directory

Comment: Why are you even trying to run the .kv file?  That's just data, the .py file is your actual program.

Answer (score 0):

> The content of the file should always start with the Kivy header, where version must be replaced with the Kivy language version you’re using. For now, use 1.0

Source: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html

So you need to add `#:kivy <version>`, ex: `#:kivy 1.9.2` at the top of your .kv file.

Comment: Which is necessarily not the case, since I have never countered any problem with the `#:kivy <version>` header not showing up in my .kv files

_Edit: Now that I remember that the case here differs between devices so maybe I should keep my mouth shut_

Comment: @Weebify The official Kivy documentation says to include it so there’s definitely a reason.